# React native error, Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: react-native

Any ideas what this error means?

When I try and run, `npm run playground-android`, I get the error.

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\sites\ReactMatt\lower-your-drinking\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\org\webkit'.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I one had similar issues. Below is how I fixed it.

```
cd android //Navigate into the android folder from the root directory
./gradlew clean // Run this
```

I hope it helps

Comment: its giving same error for me even after running above command

Answer (score 3):

On windows 
     i resolved by

```
1. cd android
2. ./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to close Android Studio while building through the CLI

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem but gradlew clean did not resolve issue until I removed the android and ios folders from my project and then used these commands;

- react-native eject
- react-native link
- react-native run-android

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> This works for me!

```
1) Navigate to android  :  cd android
2) Then run this command:  ./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score -1):

In your project,

1. Navigate to android => `cd android`
2. Then, run this command => `./gradlew clean`
3. Then, open your project's Android kloser from Android Studio and Build Gradle
   [image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, if you watch this video it may help you

https://youtu.be/jBuAbqoGW-0